# How to add the text “ON” and “OFF” to Switch toggle button in angular using primeng?

Tags: angular, primeng, togglebutton

I'm using primeng in my angular14 project. I want to show ON and OFF label inside switch toggle button.May be somebody know how to do that?

```
<p-inputSwitch ></p-inputSwitch>
```

https://primeng.org/inputswitch

I tried to manage this problem with CSS classes, unfortunately it was not successful

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow your initial approach with CSS classes and got an example running:

Template:

```html
<div class="custom-switch">
  <div class="switch-container">
    <span class="switch-label">{{ isOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF' }}</span>
    <p-inputSwitch [(ngModel)]="isOn"></p-inputSwitch>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.custom-switch {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 8px;
}

.switch-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.switch-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

Maybe you had the same idea and just missed the z-index, because I had to set it to see the label above/inside the input switch. To make it a beautiful component you might have to play with some more styling regarding size and fonts, but for a starting point it works.